# XPath Recursive Descent behaves differently between match and select

Tags: xslt

**Info**

Why is there different behaviour of Recursive Descent operator between

●   template's match attribute where it is ignored and only children are selected ignoring their descendants

●   for-each's select attribute where it works properly

Two examples of test.xsl are given which both operate on the following test.xml.

*test.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.xsl"?>

<people>

  <person id="(1)">
    <name>Lucy</name>
  </person>  

  <class>

    <person id="(2)">
      <name>David</name>
      <person id="(21)">
        <name>David</name>
      </person>
    </person>

  </class>    

</people>
```

**match="//person"**

In this example we are trying to use match="//person" to select ALL
person elements from document which doesn't work.   Instead of
selecting ALL root descendants person elements, person elements which
are inside other person elements (like id="(21)") are not
included.

*test.xsl*

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="text()"/>  

  <xsl:template match="//person">
    <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

*output.xml*

```
(1)(2)
```

**select="//person"**

In this example we are using select="//person" to select ALL person
elements from the document.     This will properly select ALL root
descendants person elements including id="(21)".    Value of
match="class" is irrelevant since select="//person" uses absolute
path.

*test.xsl*

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="text()"/>  

  <xsl:template match="class">
    <xsl:for-each select="//person">  
      <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
    </xsl:for-each>  
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

*output.xml*

```
(1)(2)(21)
```

Comment: These are not 'recursive descent operators'. Recursive descent is a parsing technique, not an operator class, and it may or may not be used by an XPath or XSLT implementation.

Comment: I was under impression that '//' is called Recursive descent. If not how is it called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a difference between a *match pattern* and  a *select expression*. A match pattern does not select anything - it is only used to see if the current node matches the pattern. For this reason, the match pattern `match="//person"` is the same as `match="person"`.

If a node never gets to be the current node (i.e. templates are not *applied* to it), then it doesn't matter if it matches any template's match pattern or not. This is shown in your first example: the [built-in template rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#built-in-rule) are applied recursively until the `<person id="(2)">` node is encountered; this matches a pattern of a more specific template - but that template has no instructions to apply templates to any of its descendants, so the chain breaks at this point, and the node `<person id="(21)">` is never examined to see if there is a template matching it.

Comment: This sounds very confusing since the difference is so subtle between matching and selecting. You are saying that templating engine has its own default built in logic for iterating through elements on which I have no influence. During iteration every element is checked if it matches some template and if so it is taken out without going inside it. So match attribute deosn't define how to select elements. And for-each behaves like selecting and matching is built into the same attribute.

Comment: In other words for-each doesn't have one attribute for selecting elements and one for matching them in contrast to templates which have differe attribute for selecting (hidden one) and matching (exposed one).

Comment: **1.** I don't think the difference is subtle. -- **2.** XSLT *does* have a default behavior (see the link in my answer), which your templates can override. The default template applied to an element includes an `<xsl:apply-templates/>` instruction; your template doesn't. That's what breaks the recursion.

Comment: With subtle I ment that templating engine has two parameters - one for selecting and one for matching elements. While for-each has only one parameters which is used for both selecting and matching. I presume that for-each could have be done to also have two parameters - one that defines how to iterate through elements and one for matching them. Then we would have consistency in how different parts of framework work which would make it easier to understand and use.

Comment: What would be the reason for making these two things so radically different? On the surface they do the same thing - select elements. But under the surface they are doing it in a such a profoundly different way that it is hard to keep such different apraoches to the same problem simultaniously in ones head. This is made worse without some explanations what was the reason for. Tutorials usually explain how things work but they don't bother explaining why they work the way they do.

Comment: A better way, IMHO, to think about this is that XSLT offers two different paradigms (sometimes called "push" and "pull') for you to choose from. One uses a combination of `<xsl:apply-templates select="..."/>` and `<xsl:template match="...">`, while the other uses only `<xsl:for-each select="...">`.

Answer (score 0):

Well a `template` with a `match` on its own does not cause any processing and your template with

```
  <xsl:template match="//person">
    <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

outputs the `id` attribute and does no further processing. So you will need to make sure you have an `apply-templates` e.g.

```
  <xsl:template match="//person">
    <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>
```

or you will need a template like

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="//person"/>
</xsl:template>
```

that makes sure all `person` elements are processed.

Also note that a `match="//person"` is the same as `match="person"` so all you need is

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="//person"/>
</xsl:template>
```

and

```
  <xsl:template match="person">
    <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
  </xsl:template>
```